# Parsing a file with special format using python to a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, file, parsing, dictionary

I have a file with the following format:

```
X ={
    a= "someText";
    b = 0;
    c = 1;
    d ={
           t = "someText3";
        };
    f ="someText2";
};
X ={
    a= "someText4";
    b = 20;
    c = 40;
    f ="someText6";
    d ={
        t = "someText5";
    };
};
```

I am looking for a smart and robust way to parse it to a list of dict like the following:

```
X[0] = {'a':"someText",'b':0, 'c':0, 'd':{ 't':'SomeText3' }, 'f':"someText2"}
X[1] = {'a':"someText4",'b':20, 'c':40, 'd':{ 't':'SomeText5' }, 'f':"someText6"}
```

Note that there might be nested dictionaries and the variables can have different order of occurrence.

My method is to keep track of the level by searching '={' and '};' and construct the list. I wonder if there is an elegant method to parse it.

Comment: On Stack Overflow you must show code and we will help you fix it. Please attempt it firstly.

Comment: The best solution is to avoid whatever home-brewed text-serialization format this is and use JSON or YAML.

Comment: If you can't preprocess the input file's syntax into something that conforms to a known language (JSON, Python, etc), and you must accept it as it is, then the only robust way to parse it is to write a full-on parser, for which you need a proper grammar. For example, are the variables (like `X`) and the dictionary keys (like `a`...`f` and `t`) always a single alpha character or can they be similar to programming language identifiers, and if so, how similar? Is the only data structure a dictionary or are there others? Is the semicolon after the last value in a dictionary mandatory or optional?

Answer (score 2):

The simple parser below implements a [recursive descent algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) on simple dictionionary schemes:

```
import re
from collections import namedtuple
s = """ 
X ={
   a= "someText";
   b = 0;
   c = 1;
   d ={
       t = "someText3";
    };
  f ="someText2";
 };


"""
s1 = """
  X ={
   a= "someText4";
   b = 20;
   c = 40;
   f ="someText6";
   d ={
     t = "someText5";
   };
};
"""

token = namedtuple('token', ['type', 'value'])

class Parser:
    lang = r'"[a-zA-Z0-9]+"|[a-zA-Z]+|\d+|\{|\};'
    token_types = {'int':'\d+', 'key':'[a-zA-Z]+', 'start':'{', 'end':'};'}
    def __init__(self, s):
       self.starting_with = Parser.tokenize(s)[1:-1]
       self.tokens = iter(Parser.tokenize(s)[1:-1])
       self.starts = []
       self.ends = []
       self.k_list = []
       self.k = None
       self.d = {}
       self.current_d = {}
    def parse(self):
       current = next(self.tokens, None)
       if current:
         if current.type == 'start':
           self.starts.append(current.value)
           self.parse()
         if current.type == 'key':
           self.k = current.value
           self.k_list.append(self.k)
           self.parse()
         if current.type not in ['start', 'end', 'key']:
           if len(self.starts) == 1:
             self.d[self.k] = current.value[1:-1] if current.value.startswith('"') and current.value.endswith('"') else current.value
             self.parse()
           else:
             self.current_d[self.k_list[-1]] = current.value[1:-1] if current.value.startswith('"') and current.value.endswith('"') else current.value
             self.parse()
         if current.type == 'end':
           end = self.starts.pop()
           self.d[self.k_list[-len(self.starts)-1]] = self.current_d
           self.current_d = {}
           self.parse()
    @classmethod
    def tokenize(cls, s):
       return [token('string' if i.startswith('"') and i.endswith('"') else [a for a, b in cls.token_types.items() if re.findall(b, i)][0], i) for i in re.findall(cls.lang, s)]




dictionaries = [s, s1]
X = []
for d in dictionaries:
   p = Parser(d)
   p.parse()
   X.append(p.d) 

print(X[0])
print(X[1])
```

Output:

```
{'a': 'someText', 'c': '1', 'b': '0', 'd': {'t': 'someText3'}, 'f': 'someText2'}
{'a': 'someText4', 'c': '40', 'b': '20', 'd': {'t': 'someText5'}, 'f': 'someText6'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without having an IQ of 170, by using [pyparsing](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyparsing/2.0.3). Mind you, I've found that it takes some time to learn it.

I have defined the grammar of your input in seven lines. `result` is used to house the labelled pieces that pyparsing finds. Then the final lines of the code contructs what you want from the parsed items. The bits of code that include `previous` constitute a hideous kluge that I needed because my grammar finds the `var` elements twice. Perhaps you can find the flaw?

```
input = '''\
X ={
    a= "someText";
    b = 0;
    c = 1;
    d ={
           t = "someText3";
        };
    f ="someText2";
};
X ={
    a= "someText4";
    b = 20;
    c = 40;
    f ="someText6";
    d ={
        t = "someText5";
    };
};'''

import pyparsing as pp

result = []
var = pp.Word(pp.alphas).setParseAction(lambda s: result.append(('var', s[0])))
equals = pp.Literal('=')
semicolon = pp.Literal(';')
a_string = pp.QuotedString('"').setParseAction(lambda s: result.append(('string', s[0])))
number = pp.Word(pp.nums).setParseAction(lambda s: result.append(('number', s[0])))
open_curly = pp.Literal('{').setParseAction(lambda s: result.append(('dict_open', None)))
close_curly = pp.Literal('}').setParseAction(lambda s: result.append(('dict_close', None)))

one_dict = pp.Forward()
simple = var + equals + pp.Or([a_string, number]) + semicolon
declaration = one_dict | simple
one_dict << var + equals + open_curly + pp.OneOrMore(declaration) + close_curly + semicolon
dict_list = pp.OneOrMore(one_dict)

dict_list.parseString(input)

count = 0
previous = None
for item in result:
    if item[0] == 'var':
        if item[1] == 'X':
            print ('\nX[{:d}] = '.format(count), end='')
            count += 1
        else:
            if item == previous:
                continue
            print ('{}: '.format(item[1]), end='')
            previous = item
    elif item[0] == 'dict_open':
        print ('{ ', end='')
    elif item[0] == 'dict_close':
        print ('}', end='')
    elif item[0] == 'number':
        print ('{}, '.format(item[1]), end='')
    elif item[0] == 'string':
        print ('"{}", '.format(item[1]), end='')
    else:
        pass
print ()
```

Result:

```
X[0] = { a: "someText", b: 0, c: 1, d: { t: "someText3", }f: "someText2", }
X[1] = { a: "someText4", b: 20, c: 40, f: "someText6", d: { t: "someText5", }}
```

**Edit**: If it's possible for dictionaries to be empty then substitute the following line in the code above.

```
one_dict << var + equals + open_curly + pp.ZeroOrMore(declaration) + close_curly + semicolon
```

Comment: Nice use of `pyparsing`. I will have to learn more about it :)

Comment: @Ajax1234: Thank you. I have a lot to learn about it myself. :-)

Comment: @hnourzad: You're most welcome. If Ajax' solution does what you want you should mark it accepted.

Comment: I just realized that that the code needs some modifications to handle possible empty dictionaries. Any suggestion?
Also here is a quick reference on pyparsing:
http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pyparsing/pyparsing.pdf

Comment: @hnourzad: Please see the edit, and, thank you, I've seen that documentation. It's one that I use myself.

Comment: @ Bill Bell: Awesome.

Comment: Don't I wish I'd invented that software!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation using [parsy](https://github.com/python-parsy/parsy) (which works similarly to pyparsing but is more modern and has much nicer documentation, and generally results in much neater code, but does require Python 3.3 or greater):

```
from collections import defaultdict

from parsy import generate, regex, seq, string, whitespace

lexeme = lambda parser: whitespace.optional() >> parser << whitespace.optional()
variable = lexeme(regex(r"[A-Za-z]+"))
string_literal = lexeme(string('"') >> regex(r'[^"]*') << string('"'))
int_literal = lexeme(regex(r'[0-9]+').map(int))

@generate
def value():
    return (yield dict_literal | string_literal | int_literal)


statement = seq(variable << lexeme(string("=")),
                value << lexeme(string(";")))
dict_literal = lexeme(string("{")) >> statement.many().map(dict) << lexeme(string("}"))
file_format = statement.many()


def parse(text_input):
    output = defaultdict(list)
    for key, val in file_format.parse(text_input):
        output[key].append(val)
    return dict(output)
```

Output for your example:

```
{'X': [{'a': 'someText',
   'b': 0,
   'c': 1,
   'd': {'t': 'someText3'},
   'f': 'someText2'},
  {'a': 'someText4',
   'b': 20,
   'c': 40,
   'd': {'t': 'someText5'},
   'f': 'someText6'}]}
```

The parsing is done by `file_format.parse`, the `parse` function I've added then combines that basic parse into a dictionary with multiple entries for each top level variable, and returns that value. It doesn't print it exactly as per your example because that probably isn't what you need if you want to use the values from Python.

You might want to adjust this according to your needs. Also, you may need to adjust all of the sub-parsers according to your actual rules (e.g. can variable names contain numbers? Are there escapes for string literals?).

Comment: Beautiful and simple !

Comment: @ spookylukey Just want to add that parsy requires Python 3.3 or greater.

Comment: Thanks @hnourzad, added that now.

Comment: I have another question. I have some files that are formatted like the following: 
X.a="someText";
X.b=0;
X.c=1;
X.d = { t = "someText3";}
X.f = "SomeText2";
X.a="someText4";
X.b=20;
X.c=40;
X.f = "someText6";
X.d = { t = "someText5";}
Again same output expected. How do you handle such case with parsy? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I find plex even easier to apply here. Just eight expressions to scan for.

```
from io import StringIO

input = StringIO(
'''X ={
    a= "someText";
    b = 0;
    c = 1;
    d ={
           t = "someText3";
        };
    f ="someText2";
};
X ={
    a= "someText4";
    b = 20;
    c = 40;
    f ="someText6";
    d ={
        t = "someText5";
    };
};''')

from plex import *
from io import StringIO

space = Any(' \t\n')

lexicon = Lexicon([
    (Rep1(Range('AZaz')), 'var'),
    (Str('"') + Rep(AnyBut('"')) + Str('"'), 'quoted'),
    (Rep1(Range('09')), 'number'),
    (space, IGNORE),
    (Str('='), IGNORE),
    (Str(';'), IGNORE),
    (Str('{'), 'open_curly'),
    (Str('}'), 'close_curly'),
])

scanner = Scanner(lexicon, input)
count = 0
while True:
    token = scanner.read()
    if token[0] is None:
        break
    elif token[0] in ['var', 'number']:
        if token[1]=='X':
            print ('\nX[{:d}] = '.format(count),end='')
            count += 1
        else:
            print ('{}: '.format(token[1]),end='')
    elif token[0]=='quoted':
        print('{}, '.format(token[1]), end='')
    elif token[0] == 'open_curly':
        print ('{} '.format(token[1]), end='')
    elif token[0] == 'close_curly':
        print ('{}, '.format(token[1]), end='')
    else:
        pass
print ()
```

Result:

```
X[0] = { a: "someText", b: 0: c: 1: d: { t: "someText3", }, f: "someText2", }, 
X[1] = { a: "someText4", b: 20: c: 40: f: "someText6", d: { t: "someText5", }, },
```

The heavy downside is the it's distributed for Py2 only AFAIK. However, was able to make it work for Py3 in about two hours.